# How to get page count using Kaminari

Tags: kaminari

I am iterating through a large array of model objects and need to paginate for performance/memory reasons.

I want to do something like this:

```
for i in 1..Person.num_pages
  Person.page(i).each do
    # work
  end
end
```

Obviously I can get the count and do the math myself, but is there an equivalent of num_pages? 
Or is there a more elegant way of doing this altogether?

Answer (score 42):

#### Use `total_pages`.

Yes, you can use `total_pages` to retrieve the total number of pages in your model.

For example:

```
@blog_entries = Blog.all.page(1).per(20)
puts "total pages: #{@blog_entries.total_pages}"
```

#### Version < 0.14.0

Previous to version 0.14.0, the method was called `num_pages` instead of `total_pages`.

Comment: `num_pages` has been renamed to `total_pages` in version 0.14.0 ([commit](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/commit/e79935c2d596e165be566f6d92eed8d5acd6a843))

Comment: If you are using the default `per`, just do `Blog.all.page(1).total_pages`

Comment: Doc "Module: Kaminari::PageScopeMethods":  https://www.rubydoc.info/github/amatsuda/kaminari/master/Kaminari/PageScopeMethods